# can't figure out how to make the bullet move with animation in turtle module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

hi im trying to build the space invaders game with the turtle module in python and i cant seem to figure out a way to make the bullet (which is just another turtle in a shape of a circle) move upwards while showing the animation that it's moving, because when i press x on my keyboard to shoot it just shifts immediately to the desired height without showing animation

here is the main code file

```
from turtle import *
from space_ship import Ship
import time
import keyboard


window = Screen()
window.setup(width=1000, height=600)
window.bgcolor("black")
window.tracer(0)
window.listen()


ship = Ship((0, -270))


window.onkeypress(key="Right", fun=ship.move_right)
window.onkeypress(key="Left", fun=ship.move_left)


end = False
while end == False:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    window.update()

    if keyboard.is_pressed("x"):
        ship.create_bullet()


window.mainloop()
```

and here is the file for the ship (maybe we need to change something in the create bullet method)

```
from turtle import *
import time


class Ship(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, destination):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_len=8, stretch_wid=2)
        self.goto(destination)
        self.current_x = self.xcor()
        self.current_y = self.ycor()

    def move_right(self):
        self.forward(10)

    def move_left(self):
        self.back(10)

    def create_bullet(self):
        bullet = Turtle()
        bullet.penup()
        bullet.shape("circle")
        bullet.color("white")
        bullet.setheading(90)
        destination = (self.current_x, self.current_y)
        bullet.goto(destination)
        move_y = 10
        for _ in range(20):
            time.sleep(0.01)
            new_y = bullet.ycor() + move_y
            bullet.goto(bullet.xcor(), new_y)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you're missing a `screen.update()` call after your `bullet.goto(bullet.xcor(), new_y)` call.

The longer answer is your code structure is setup incorrectly.  I've seen no end of questions where folks have `update()` in an (effectively) endless loop.  Generally, you should get your code working without `tracer()` and `update()` first, and then add them after it's funtional to speed up the animation.  Here's a rework of your code that fixes the issue you asked about and adjusts the issue I mentioned:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Ship(Turtle):
    BULLET_MOVE_Y = 10

    def __init__(self, destination):
        super().__init__()

        self.shape('square')
        self.color('white')
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_len=8, stretch_wid=2)
        self.goto(destination)

        screen.update()

    def move_right(self):
        self.forward(10)
        screen.update()

    def move_left(self):
        self.backward(10)
        screen.update()

    def create_bullet(self):
        bullet = Turtle()
        bullet.penup()
        bullet.shape('circle')
        bullet.color('white')
        bullet.setheading(90)
        bullet.goto(self.position())

        for _ in range(20):
            bullet.forward(Ship.BULLET_MOVE_Y)
            screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1000, height=600)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(False)

ship = Ship((0, -270))

screen.onkeypress(key='Right', fun=ship.move_right)
screen.onkeypress(key='Left', fun=ship.move_left)
screen.onkeypress(key='x', fun=ship.create_bullet)

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

A problem you're likely to run into eventually is that your bullet animation stops all other (invader) animation while it's happening.  This can be fixed using timer events via `ontimer()`.